# Compare a value(in dict) in one list with another list [Python]

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I have two list(and dict inside) like this;

```
list1 = [
    {'ID': 0, 'IP': '192.168.1.1', 'Hostname': 'hostname1'}, 
    {'ID': 1, 'IP': '192.168.1.2', 'Hostname': 'hostname2'}, 
    {'ID': 2, 'IP': '192.168.1.3', 'Hostname': 'hostname3'}, 
    {'ID': 3, 'IP': '192.168.1.4', 'Hostname': 'hostname4'}
]
```

```
list2= [
    {'Q1': 'HOST_hostname9_192.168.9.0', 'Time' :'Fri, 13 Aug 2021 03:25:01 +0300'},
    {'Q1': 'HOST_hostname3_192.168.9.4', 'Time' :'Tue, 17 Aug 2021 13:48:39 +0300'},
    {'Q1': 'HOST_hostname7_192.168.1.2', 'Time' :'Fri, 13 Aug 2021 03:25:01 +0300'}
]
```

I want to search the data in the **'IP'** or '**Hostname**' fields in **list1**,, in **Q1** in the **list2**. I want to output okey if any and no if not.

For example;
'**192.168.1.2**' is in the Q1 and output is OKAY or '**hostname3**' is the same, output is OKAY.
However, **192.168.1.1** and **hostname1** (We can think of these data as interconnected.), It should give NO output because it cannot be found in any Q1.

I hope I could explain.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Correct your code for `list1` as it wouldn't run as is.

Comment: Why does `192.168.1.2` output `hostname3`. It seems related to `hostname2` in `list1` and `hostname7` in `list2`.

Answer (score 0):

ips= {y.get("IP", ""):y.get("hostnames","") for y in list1}
result= [ y.get("hostname",None) for y in list2 if y.get("hostname",None) in ips.values()]

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to answer the question, if I've understood it...

> or example; '192.168.1.2' is in the Q1 and output is OKAY or
> 'hostname3' is the same,

```
list1 = [
{'ID': 0, 'IP': '192.168.1.1', 'Hostname': 'hostname1'}, 
{'ID': 1, 'IP': '192.168.1.2', 'Hostname': 'hostname2'}, 
{'ID': 2, 'IP': '192.168.1.3', 'Hostname': 'hostname3'}, 
{'ID': 3, 'IP': '192.168.1.4', 'Hostname': 'hostname4'}]

list2= [
    {'Q1': 'HOST_hostname9_192.168.9.0', 'Time' :'Fri, 13 Aug 2021 03:25:01 +0300'},
    {'Q1': 'HOST_hostname3_192.168.9.4', 'Time' :'Tue, 17 Aug 2021 13:48:39 +0300'},
    {'Q1': 'HOST_hostname7_192.168.1.2', 'Time' :'Fri, 13 Aug 2021 03:25:01 +0300'}
   ]

#brutal or clever?  hmmm...
x = str(list2)

for item in list1:
    for key in item.keys():
        if key in ['IP', 'Hostname']:
            if item[key] in x:
                print('OK', item[key])

#>> OK 192.168.1.2
#>> OK hostname3
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to maintenance data is using database. You can check https://www.xplenty.com/blog/which-database/ to find the best database for your case...
but for this question you can try this code:

```
  error = None
  for obj in list2:
      for key in obj.keys():
          if key is 'Q1' or key is 'Hostname':
              print(obj[key])
          else:
              error = "Not Found"
  if error:
      print(error)
```

I hope I could help ;)